# What does "ERROR: fstsymbols: Saving osymbols but there are no output symbols" means and how can i solve it?

Tags: openfst, vosk

I wanted to update the language model of Kaldi model used in Vosk. I was following the Updating the language model in [Vosk Adaptation](https://alphacephei.com/vosk/adaptation)

I had this **ERROR: fstsymbols: Saving osymbols but there are no output symbols** when I try to run `fstsymbols --save_osymbols=words.txt Gr.fst > /dev/null` .
I guess the words.txt is the new text which I want to recognize right?

Answer (score 0):

What this command does is it saves all the output symbol table of the current finite state transducer (language model @ .fst file) into a text file called `words.txt`.

```bash
$ fstsymbols --help
...
  --save_osymbols: type = string, default = ""
  Save fst file's output symbol table to file
...
```

This file would be used in the next command, where `text.txt` is a file containing your custom list of words.

```bash
farcompilestrings --fst_type=compact --symbols=words.txt --keep_symbols text.txt | \
 ngramcount | ngrammake | \
 fstconvert --fst_type=ngram > Gr.new.fst
```